# Place Chart js data point in middle of week when x axis is time Cartesian with type week

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying generate one chart with chart js plugin (version 3) and trying to use the x axis as pe this [doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units) with type being set to to time and time unit is week. I am using `date-fns` adapter which is recommended by it's author with chartjs library.

I am using alpine js for init purpose and to use it easily for date manipulation purpose. Everything is working fine.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.12.0/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>


<div class="project-progress-chart-wrapper" style="position: relative; padding-top:50%; padding-top:min(50%,530px)">
                    <div style="position:absolute;width: 100%;height:100%;left: 0;top: 0">
                        <canvas  id="project-progress-chart"
                            @shownextdata.window="function() {
                                const nextDate = getFourWeeksNextDate();
                                currentDate = new Date(nextDate);
                                initChartData();
                            }"
                            @showpreviousdata.window="() => {
                                const prevDate = getFourWeeksEarlierDate();
                                currentDate = new Date(prevDate);
                                initChartData();
                            }"
                            x-data="{
                                chartInstance: null,
                                init() {
                                    this.initChartData();
                                },
                                currentDate: new Date(),
                                numberOfProgressWeeks: 24,
                                getFourWeeksEarlierDate(){
                                    const date = new Date(this.currentDate);
                                    date.setDate(date.getDate() - (this.numberOfProgressWeeks * 7));
                                    return date;
                                },
                                getFourWeeksNextDate(){
                                    const date = new Date(this.currentDate);
                                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (this.numberOfProgressWeeks * 7));
                                    return date;
                                },

                                generateChartData() {
                                    const data = [],
                                        lastSunday = this.getLastSunday(),
                                        tempLoopDate = new Date(lastSunday);

                                    while(this.getFourWeeksEarlierDate() <= tempLoopDate) {
                                        data.push({
                                            x: new Date(tempLoopDate).toISOString().split('T')[0],
                                            y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
                                        })
                                        tempLoopDate.setDate(tempLoopDate.getDate() - 7)
                                    }

                                    return data;

                                   
                                },
                                getLastSunday() {
                                    const lastSunday = new Date(this.currentDate);
                                    lastSunday.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() -  this.currentDate.getDay());
                                    return lastSunday;
                                },
                               
                                initChartData() {
                                    //setting up data
                                    const data = this.generateChartData(),
                                        progressChartData =  {
                                            datasets: [
                                                {
                                                    label: 'This Week',
                                                    fill: !0,
                                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                                    borderColor: 'rgba(2, 132, 199, 1)',
                                                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(2, 132, 199, 1)',
                                                    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
                                                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                                                    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(2, 132, 199, 1)',
                                                    data: data,
                                                }
                                            ],
                                        };

                                    //setting up config

                                    const config = {
                                        type: 'line',
                                        data: progressChartData,
                                        options: {
                                            maintainAspectRatio: false,
                                            plugins: {
                                                legend: {
                                                    display: false
                                                },
                                                tooltip: {
                                                    
                                                }
                                            },
                                            scales: {
                                                x: {
                                                    type: 'time',
                                                    time: {
                                                        unit: 'week',
                                                        displayFormats: {
                                                            quarter: 'MMM yyyy'
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    this.chartInstance && this.chartInstance.destroy();

                                    //initialization
                                    null !== this.$el && (this.chartInstance = new Chart(this.$el, config));
                                }
                            }">
                        </canvas>
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
```

But what i am trying to achive is to associate the chart js x-data with kind of `week` rather than date and thus trying to place data point in the middle of week instead of at the edge of date.

I am trying to achive something like this where it is even possible to hover and change week background as data is associated with week and not date. And also as we can see, month only starts when first sunday of month comes. Sometimes month is longer when 5 weeks and sometimes shorter.
[image]

But what I finally end up with is this.
[image]

Can anyone please help how to associate data with weeks and thus trying to generate array of objects where week should be in focus and not date?

i.e. array of {x: '2023-W1', y: 10} instead of {x: '2023-01-01', y: 10} so that 10 (which is y value) comes in middle of week 1?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to change the alignment of the axis labels. It seems to me they are right aligned.
If this, does not work, try overriding the axis and build your own one.

Comment: Hi if you can just explain what this *controlPointPreviousX* and *controlPointNextX* in this code and how to access them, then it would be helpful. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700096/how-to-add-an-offset-to-a-dataset-in-chart-js

I think it is the exact answer thatI am looking for but not getting the code with new version of chart js.

Comment: It is shown how is can be accessed in the example. Just create a new plugin and inside it try to retrieve the model of the dataset.
Just try to console log the dataset output and search for the model prop.
otherwise, refer to the chart.js migration guide.